# What is meaning of : remains theoretically intact?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Sri Lanka, a 2001 ceasefire between the government and the Tamil Tigers, fighting for an independent homeland in the north and east of the island state, broke down in 2005 when both parties resumed their 20-year struggle.
Ironically, **while the ceasefire remains theoretically intact**, an estimated 7,000 people have since died in renewed fighting.
"this text is from a book"

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is confusing you about the clause in bold? Are there unfamiliar words in it, or is it put together in a way that makes you think it should mean something it clearly doesn't, or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain the meaning of this whole passage first:

> Ironically, **while the ceasefire remains theoretically intact**, an estimated 7,000 people have since died in renewed fighting.

The above means:

> Even though the government and the Tamil Tigers are, on paper (officially), no longer meant to be fighting, 7000 people have died in fights anyway.

So, your bolded bit means:

> even though there is officially still a ceasefire

Breakdown of words (in context):

- theoretically = in theory, e.g. this should be the case, but it isn't
- intact = still exists (the ceasefire still exists)